# Export from .xls to .sql / creating sql queries

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin, converters, xls

Okay guys, I've been having this problem for a few weeks now and I'm getting no-where with it. I have OpenOffice and regular Office softwares. Both produce flawed .csv files, or at least phpMyAdmin can't read neither of these. Yes, I've been trying to change server's settings of uploading, etc. I also tried to contact my web hosting service and they claimed that all the .csv files I've produced are flawed.

Anyway, I'm looking for a way to convert .xls table to SQL. Most of the softwares out there cost money that I don't have. Furthermore, I've seen PHP systems that do just that, so I know this is possible.

Comment: Have you checked that your CSV and MyPhpAdmin use the same separater (comma, semicolon, tab, ...)? Anyway, if you want to generate INSERTs from Excel, an easy way is to generate the inserts as an additional column and save just this column as text later on. See the second answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818796/generate-sql-insert-script-from-excel-worksheet) question.

Comment: What do you mean with "regular Office software"? And what exaclty do you mean with "flawed .csv files"? Can you show an example of an supposedly "flawed" file? And what you expect instead?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - regular: Microsoft's. And I've no idea what is flawed. Iv'e been working on fixing the problem for a few days now (inside the .csv files) and it seems as though I getting no-where. I expect to be introduced to some kind of free software/website/method to convert xls sheet to sql.

Comment: @Fabian - doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

No need converted to. sql, you can import directly with phpmyadmin or using tools like navicat for mysql in phpmyadmin go to the option to import, find the file, select the file type (csv or csv loaddata), in part below defines the column separator (if you do not know which opens the file with notepad)

if a very large file using navicat.

Flawed is "defective"?. I assume you have problem with excel, maybe you have defined the same column separator for separating thousands or decimals, use openoffice to open the file