# Bulk insert an excel sheet with JAVA

Tags: java, excel, bulk

I'm looking for a way to bulk insert data from an excel sheet to a table in the database (eg. SQLServer). Didn't find any solution to do it (that is not to save as a CSV or txt file). 
Any suggestions?
thanks

Comment: You haven't looked hard enough

Comment: There are several SO questions on this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16818796/940217

Comment: Read Excel with `Apache POI` and write to db with `JDBC`.

Comment: There are tons of answers on S.O. about this, and a simple Google will turn up APIs you can use also.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could have a ETL tool. extract transform load. Pentaho has free version of this. Hope it helps.