# Compare table content with external file- SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, oracle, db2

I have an Excel file with users IDs, called `users Excel`.

In the Database I have a `users` table: this table holds the data from the users excel file and from another file (administrators file).

I would like to check if I have a user in the `users Excel` which does not exist in the table.

Should I build a virtual table? how?

Comment: Why do you have **multiple DB tags**?

Answer (score 3):

**EXCEL method**

No need of creating external tables and loading etc.

The simplest way would be -

1. `SPOOL` the table data to a file.
2. Copy the contents of this spooled file and your `users Excel` to a common file.
3. Just do a compare using `VLOOKUP`.

**UPDATE** Some more short cuts -

**Pure SQL method**

1. Generate the SQL queries using `excel string addition operator – &`.

Example -

`="insert into customers values('" &B3 &"','" & C3 & "','"&D3&"');"`

where B3, C3, D3 refer to the cells. See an example here [Generate sql insert script from excel worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818796/generate-sql-insert-script-from-excel-worksheet)

2. Now, just `create` a table in your database with the required columns.
3. Copy and Execute the `INSERT` statements.
4. Compare the two tables using a `MINUS` query.

For example,

```
select user from db_table
MINUS
select user from excel_table
```

Comment: ' Thanks. That is a good idea- upvoted. but I still would like to do it via a query.

Comment: I will tell you a small secret. You can directly create `INSERT` statements in your `EXCEL` sheet. All you need to do is, just create a table with `USER` column. And execute all the `insert` statements. And then a simple `MINUS` query to compare. Let me edit my answer and add this.

Comment: Thanks. Is it a virtual table? can I delete it easily after use?

Comment: you can just do `DROP TABLE table_name PURGE` when you are done with your analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You can load your Excel file content into a temporary table and compare the content with the existing table.

I guess you are on a windows environment:

1- Export the content of the excel file to a simple text file (users.txt)

2- Create the temporary table: 
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE users_tmp (user_id int) ENGINE = MEMORY;

3- Load the data file content to the tmp table: 
   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'users.txt' INTO TABLE users_tmp LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';

Then compare users to users_tmp content.

Comment: Thanks, how can I delete the temporary table after use?

Comment: You can simply use "DROP TABLE ...". Note also that the temporary table is only visible for the current connection, it is automatically dropped if you close the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can try by creating virtual/temporary table having syntax `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_users(user_id INT)`.

Push the `users Excel` data into it.

Then compare `users` table with `temp_users` by writing query.

Comment: how can I  delete the temporary table after use?

Comment: Drop temporary table: https://riptutorial.com/mysql/example/20332/drop-temporary-table

Answer (score 1):

You listed several databases and no specific version… In any case, you will need to generate appropriate `SELECT`s - either in Excel as suggested by Lalit Kumar B, using some text processor, or even (partly) in your database.

For MySQL, you'd work towards the statements to be used in the subselect resulting in "T".

```
SELECT T.firstName, T.lastName FROM
  (SELECT 'Afirst' firstName, 'Alast' lastName UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Dfirst' firstName, 'Dlast') T
LEFT JOIN Users U
  ON U.firstName = T.firstName
  AND U.lastName = T.lastName
WHERE U.firstName IS NULL AND U.lastName IS NULL;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7461f/1)

In Oracle you use `DUAL` to construct the statements:

```
SELECT T.firstName, T.lastName FROM
  (SELECT 'Afirst' firstName, 'Alast' lastName FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Dfirst' firstName, 'Dlast' FROM DUAL) T
LEFT JOIN Users U
  ON U.firstName = T.firstName
  AND U.lastName = T.lastName
WHERE U.firstName IS NULL AND U.lastName IS NULL
;
```

and in more recent versions, you have the option to factor:

```
WITH
T (firstName, lastName) AS (
  SELECT 'Afirst' firstName, 'Alast' lastName FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Dfirst' firstName, 'Dlast' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT T.firstName, T.lastName
FROM T
LEFT JOIN Users U
  ON U.firstName = T.firstName
  AND U.lastName = T.lastName
WHERE U.firstName IS NULL AND U.lastName IS NULL
;
```

which would even allow to split the columns in the database (If you have more than two or three columns in your Excel to compare with the Users table, you'd probably use one of the more elaborate CSV splitting approaches - if your Oracle version permits.):

```
WITH
T (string) AS (
  SELECT 'Afirst,Alast' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Dfirst,Dlast' FROM DUAL
),
TUser (firstName, lastName) AS (
  SELECT
    SUBSTR(string, 1, INSTR(string, ',') - 1)
    , SUBSTR(string, INSTR(string, ',') + 1, LENGTH(string))
  FROM T
)
SELECT T.firstName, T.lastName
FROM TUser T
LEFT JOIN Users U
  ON U.firstName = T.firstName
  AND U.lastName = T.lastName
WHERE U.firstName IS NULL AND U.lastName IS NULL
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83c57/1)

And if some database is not as relaxed as MySQL (requiring no table in the `SELECT`), and has no equivalent for Oracle's "DUAL", you can still create such a one column / one row table and proceed.

Please comment, if and as adjustment / further detail is required.