# Insert .csv file into SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Background:**

I have a table named dbo.table, within my database Data. I then have a .csv file  named test.csv I would like to push this test.csv data into my dbo.table within my Data database. How would I go about doing this?

```
  dbo.table

  State    Customer
  Ga       John Doe


  test.csv

  State    Customer 
  NY       Carolyn King
```

**Desired Output:**

```
State    Customer
Ga       John Doe
NY       Carolyn King
```

I wish to insert test.csv data into the dbo.table.
I am currently doing a Bulk Insert:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.table
FROM 'C:\test.csv'
WITH  
     (
   FIRSTROW = 2,
   rowterminator='\n',
   fieldterminator=',',
   tablock
     );
```

However, how would I perform this with a regular Insert query?

Could I do:

```
  INSERT INTO dbo.table SELECT a.* FROM
  OPENROWSET 
          (BULK N'D:\data.csv', FORMATFILE =
           'C:\test.csv', CODEPAGE = '65001');
```

I am unsure of the CODEPAGE....

Comment: I suggest using an external table.

Comment: Ok, I know there is a way to do a regular INSERT, but am unsure about proper way of going about it. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at `OPENROWSET`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I will look at this documentation. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can directly import a csv into a table in SSMS

https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1179/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-a-database-using-sql-server-management-studio.aspx

or you can generate INSERT statements from excel like below and run them

[Generate sql insert script from excel worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818796/generate-sql-insert-script-from-excel-worksheet/16819629)

how about that! there are online tools as well
http://beautifytools.com/csv-to-sql-converter.php